# running multiples commands in one condition in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a condition and I would like two things two happen in case the condition is met. When I put them in a single if..else statement the code does not give me the desired output. But when I run them separately it works. Can you please tell me what is wrong?
What I aim to do in the first part is to create a new column called id and then use this column as row names.

```
data1 <- lapply(data, function(y) {
  lapply(y, function(z) {
    if(all(c("variable", "missing") %in% names(z))) {
      z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], sep= "_", row_number()))
      } else z
  })
})

data2 <- lapply(data1, function(y) {
  lapply(y, function(z) {
    if(all(c("variable", "missing") %in% names(z))) {
      `rownames<-`(z, z[["id"]])
      } else z
  })
})
```

This is the single statement version which doesn't work:

```
data1 <- lapply(data, function(y) {
      lapply(y, function(z) {
        if(all(c("variable", "missing") %in% names(z))) {
        z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], sep= "_", row_number()));
          `rownames<-`(z, z[["id"]])
          } else z
      })
    })
```

Comment: `z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], sep= "_", row_number()))` works as a one-liner because its result will be implicitly  returned by the function. However, because you don't assign the result with `<-` the change is not saved, so when you have multiple lines you need to use `<-`, change it to `z <- z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], sep= "_", row_number()))` and it will work in the multi-line statement.

Comment: Side notes: `paste0(z[["variable"]], sep = "_", row_number())` is a little sloppy, the `paste0` function does not recognize the `sep=` argument like `paste` does, so it is merely placing the literal `"_"` ... which works here. Alternatively, use either `paste0(z[["variable"]], "_", row_number())` or `paste(z[["variable"]], row_number(), sep = "_")`. Also, for your `\`rownames<-\`` trick, you may also consider `tibble::column_to_rownames(z, "id")` since you're already using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], sep= "_", row_number()))` works as a one-liner because its result will be implicitly  returned by the function. However, because you don't assign the result with `<-` the change is not saved, so when you have multiple lines you need to use `<-`, change it to `z <- z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], sep= "_", row_number()))` and it will work in the multi-line statement.

```
data1 <- lapply(data, function(y) {
      lapply(y, function(z) {
        if(all(c("variable", "missing") %in% names(z))) {
          ## simplifying paste per r2evans's comment
          z <- z %>% mutate(id = paste0(z[["variable"]], "_", row_number()))
          ## I'd switch your row-names to a normal assignment for readability
          rownames(z) <- z[["id"]]
          ## the last thing will be returned
          z
        } else z
      })
    })
```

Comment: fwiw, `\`rownames<-\`` returns `z` with the row names attribute updated, it can work as the last expression

Comment: Yes, I just don't find it very readable.

Comment: I just ran into a problem. Doing this changes my list to a single vector including id values.

Comment: In that case please share a little bit of sample input and the expected output so we can test - without that we can't see any problems.

Comment: @Rara, if you use `rownames(z) <- z[["id"]]` as the last expression, note that _that_ is different than using `\`rownames<-\`(z, z[["id"]])`: the former returns the `character` vector whereas the latter returns the whole frame, updated.

Comment: @r2evans Wonderful! Works perfectly now.